# Surface Integral and Symmetry

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, symmetry, surface-integrals, divergence-operator

I'm trying to find the flux(divergence) via vector surface integrals out out of a solid region that is part of a ball given by $1\leq r \leq 4$ using the inverse square field. I'm wondering whether by symmetry, the flux out of such a solid region is the flux out of a ball of radius four minus the flux out of a ball of radius one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the flux out of such a solid region is the flux out of a ball of radius four minus the flux out of a ball of radius one because the surface of the solid is the union of two spheres oriented differently which explains the negative sign in computation.

Comment: Is the bigger solid region oriented outward and smaller region oriented inward?

Comment: That was my assumption .

Comment: Is 0 the flux of the bigger solid region minus the flux of the smaller region by symmetry?

Comment: I do not think symmetry was a factor in the orientation of the boundary.